# Sorting a List of Dictionaries by a timestamp field.

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have some code which collects a list of dictionary objects from an API. One of the Dictionary Keys is a last_timestamp the rule was seen in action. I would like to be able to sort by this value, however, I have used the common methods for sorting this and neither works.

```
a = sorted(all_rules, key=itemgetter('last_timestamp'))
```

Returns the error

```
    a = sorted(all_rules, key=itemgetter('last_timestamp'))
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

all_rules is the list of dictionaries.

Comment: That error message makes it seem like you don't have a list of dictionaries; at least one thing you're trying to pass to your itemgetter is a list. I suspect that in the process of creating a [mcve], you'll see that there's a list in your list.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that the timestamp is a genuine timestamp, I.E `2018-12-08T15:00:00Z` and not a real integer. I suppose I need to find a way to convert the timestamp on the fly to an Int representation of the TimeStamp and then sort and return the ID of the rules.

Comment: You don't need to suspect anything -- the error message is telling you what the problem is.  You're trying to index into a list with a string.  Please edit your question to include a [mcve], and include the result of `print(type(all_rules), set(type(obj) for obj in all_rules))`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with the following and it worked fine:

```
all_rules = [{'last_timestamp': 1}, {'last_timestamp': 0}, {'last_timestamp': 4}]
```

In your example, the problem is probably that `all_rules` is a collection of lists, not a collection of dictionaries. In this case, `sorted` tries to apply `itemgetter('last_timestamp')` to each list, which raises that `TypeError`.

If you apply the same logic where `all_rules` is a collection of dictionaries, it will return a list of dictionaries sorted by their `'last_timestamp'` value, as long as that value is comparable (i.e. has a `__lt__` method defined), a requirement which timestamps **and** strings satisfy.

Comment: If `all_rules` were a dictionary with string keys, I think the error message would be `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`.

Comment: It is definitely a list of dictionaries. I can type verify the elements of the list and the items within. As I said above, I am probably struggling as the timestamp is in fact an actual timestamp which is considered a string.

Comment: @DSM right you are, changed it, and addressed the notion that timestamps or their string representation cannot be used to sort a list.